# read user input without maxsize in C

Tags: c, input, stdin

In C i can use the `char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream)` function to read user input from stdin. But the size of the user input is limited to `size`. 
How can i read user input of variable size?

Comment: What kind of input? Describe your specific situation you are dealing with.

Comment: i just want to read userinput from stdin. but this input can be of vairable size. it can be "a"... it also can be "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa". i don't know how to deal with this, since i have to specify a max int when calling fgets...

Comment: Computers of today tend to prefer small amounts of code and small buffers, because it fits in their cache memory more easily. Have you ever considered coding with buffers of just 1 byte where possible, rather than multiple bytes? It's far easier to extend something that uses one byte to use multiple bytes, when you have a working solution and you can afford to perform optimisations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C you are responsible for your buffers, and responsible for their size. So you can not have some dynamic buffer ready for you.
So the only solution is to use a loop (either of fgets or fgetc - depends on your processing and on your stop condition)

If you go beyond C to C++, you will find that you can accept std::string objects of variable sizes (there you need to deal with word and/or line termination instead - and loop again)

Answer (score 1):

This function reads from standard input until end-of-file is encountered, and returns the number of characters read. It should be fairly easy to modify it to read exactly one line, or alike.

```
ssize_t read_from_stdin(char **s)
{
    char buf[1024];
    char *p;
    char *tmp;

    ssize_t total;
    size_t len;
    size_t allocsize;

    if (s == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    total = 0;

    allocsize = 1024;
    p = malloc(allocsize);
    if (p == NULL) {
        *s = NULL;
        return -1;
    }

    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != NULL) {
        len = strlen(buf);

        if (total + len >= allocsize) {
            allocsize <<= 1;
            tmp = realloc(p, allocsize);
            if (tmp == NULL) {
                free(p);
                *s = NULL;
                return -1;
            }

            p = tmp;
        }

        memcpy(p + total, buf, len);
        total += len;
    }       

    p[total] = 0;
    *s = p;

    return total;
}
```

Comment: Have you seen the kind of code they use in the alioth benchmark games? It uses fseek to seek to the end of stdin, lul.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Well, not yet. Could you please share a link? (All the optimization I do here is logarithmic [as opposed to linera] reallocation).

Comment: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u32/program.php?test=regexdna&lang=gpp&id=1

Comment: This one also does it: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u32/program.php?test=regexdna&lang=gcc&id=4

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Thanks. Yeah, `ftell(stdin)` looks a bit weird :)

Comment: Indeed. It seems like relying upon that value could result in UB later on.